# What kind of questions about development tools are appropriate for Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, site-recommendation, scope

I use Emacs, and so I monitor the Emacs questions (mostly as a way to learn, I can't answer most of them) and Emacs is pretty customizable. But I imagine that other development tools are filled with menus (or whatever other unearthly situations people think it's a good idea to subject themselves to) that allow customization of e.g. syntax highlighting.

Now that Super User is up and running, should people be encouraged to push their editor questions to Super User, or does it make sense to keep them in Stack Overflow?

Comment: Here we dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25785/emacs-in-technicolor http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22963/make-the-machine-purdy

Answer (score 6):

Emacs is primarily a developer tool. Questions, assuming they're from developers, *and regarding the use of the program as a development tool*, will be best answered *by* developers. Therefore, they should be asked on SO.

Same goes for Vim, Visual Studio, Eclipse, etc.

MS Word questions, while they might also involve text editing, aren't generally programming-related in any normal sense of the word (perhaps if you're getting down-and-dirty with macros or VBA...)

OTOH, if you're trying to use MS-Word as a programmer's editor, you need serious mental help. These questions should be migrated to psychoverflow.com...

Comment: Ha, yeah. One of my first questions on SO was about using excel. I thought I would have to use VBA, but apparently everyone else thought that it was a excel minutia question and closed it O_o.<br /> More on topic: Would you consider making your editor open correctly -- correct position, files open, etc -- to be fall into your description?

Comment: @quodlibetor: probably; "setting up my development environment"-type questions seem programming-related.

Answer (score -2):

Personally, I think that since there is a "fun" tag a "customization" tag isn't unjustified.

Comment: There's only one thing everyone on Meta can agree on: we all hate fun more than anything else.